# Get Coordinates of image on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a set of divs which are dynamic, I somehow want them in a different order. So I'm using `flex` `order` to control the order of the divs. One of the div contains an image. By clicking on that image it should console the x & y coordinates of the click which is related to the image. I have made everything I want. But the problem is I'm getting the y coordinates in a negative number, I believe it is because of the order I have changed using flex.

[Here's what I tried](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtrt5j)

The expected result: When I click on the border image top left position it should console the exact position of the click which is related to the image.

Comment: Isn't that negative number caused by your own calculations?  It's also a bit weird that you write two functions inside the `getCoords()` method.  And then, those functions call each other, causing a bit of spaghetti code. Why exactly can't you just log the `x,y` coordinates of the mouse click directly? What do you want to do with those coordinates?

Comment: I'm just a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by your own calculations.
You can simplify the calculation using this function

```
GetMousePositionRelativeToTarget(e) {
    // Get the target
    const target = e.target;

    // Get the bounding rectangle of target
    const rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Mouse position
   const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
   const y = e.clientY - rect.top;

   console.log(x + ':' + y);
   return [x, y];
}
```